# WPF master detail datagridview with join in details

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, master-detail

I have two tables in Sql Server, with a master detail relation. From VS 2015, in a window (WPF), using Data Sources, I added the master table to my window. Previously I've created an EF data model. All work well. What I want to to and I'm not able is to add other two columns to details grid. These two columns can be obtained relationing detail table with another table. 
XAML was created automatically by VS, I've just wrote in code behind code for load data.

```
<Window.Resources>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="AnaSchemiPallettizzazioneMasterView" />
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="AnaSchemiPallettizzazioneDetView" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource AnaSchemiPallettizzazioneMasterView}, Path='AnaSchemiPallettizzazioneDet'}" />
```

**Master**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgAnaSchemiPallettizzazioneMaster" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" >
```

**Detail**

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dgAnaSchemiPallettizzazioneDet" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AnaSchemiPallettizzazioneDetView}}" Grid.Row="1" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
```

**Loading data**

```
 cvUnita3Fab = new dbUnita3FabEntities();

            cvSchemiMasterViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("AnaSchemiPallettizzazioneMasterView")));

            //Caricamento dei dati.
            cvUnita3Fab.AnaSchemiPallettizzazioneMaster.Load();
            cvSchemiMasterViewSource.Source = cvUnita3Fab.AnaSchemiPallettizzazioneMaster.Local;
```

[Image of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5SyH.png)

[Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txEmu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Master entity is rappresented with a class in EF model (edmx). Related tables are defined as **public virtual **

```
public partial class AnaSchemiPallettizzazioneDet
{
```

...
        public virtual AnaMateriali AnaMateriali { get; set; }
        public virtual ...
    }

In xaml window definition I've added this lines:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LunghezzaColumn" Binding="{Binding AnaMateriali.Lunghezza}" Header="Lunghezza" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="AltezzaColumn" Binding="{Binding AnaMateriali.Altezza}" Header="Altezza" />
```